# Publish apps for Android smartphones only

Tags: android

our app currently supports smartphones and tablets. We'd like to publish an update which is for smartphones only, so we need to find a way to exclude all tablets from updating to the new version. The tablet users should keep the dedicated tablet version (switch during runtime in our old app) and not receive the update, which is designed for smartphones only. Checkmarking the devices on the developer console is uncomfortable and needs to much time for keeping the list up to date. Will it be a solution to work with manifest settings like compatible-screens or supports-screens. Won't there be a problem to exclude tablets on the one side and still include smartphones with bigger displays ? Any idea ? Many thanks, Sven

Comment: Here you can find some good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605715/how-to-support-phones-up-to-4-0-excluding-tablets

Answer (score 5):

1. In AndroidManifest you can specify [supportScreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) options set.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

2. On Google Play Console, there is option for excluding certain devices (a lot of devices)

Answer (score 0):

The destinction tablets vs smartphones isn't valuable to say to least, not to say non-existent.

You should decide based on capabilities what you want. Is it just screen-size? Then go for screen-size settings. There is "smartphone with bigger display", there are only devices with a certain display size. It doesn't help to categorize a 7" device as "a really big smartphone" or "a small tablet". Why should you?

If it is about being able to call, add that to your needs.

So in the end, if it is about screen size, filter on that in the manifest and don't worry about the "smartphones with bigger displays" as you don't want to serve them. If there is something else you actually want to filter on, then do that.

Comment: the things is, that the app which is currently available in the store decides during runtime (we have a method implemented for this) if the tablet layout or the smartphone layout is used. now we want to puplish an update, which should reach the smartphone users and not the tablet users, because there's no dedicated tablet layout implemented. so the tablet users should keep their current version while the smartphone users should receive the update.

Comment: the point of my answer is that you are worrying about "smart phones with bigger displays". This is an non issue, as a 7" device is a 7" device. period. If you worry about another feature of smartphones vs tablets (something you didn't specify. landscape vs portrait? call capability? pixel density?), there are all sorts of things you can do, but the point is that the issue you seem to worry about (your last sentence) is a non-issue. That's what I tried to answer and that's what you need to worry about.